# IOException and ReadFailureException happened in spark cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using `spark-cassandra-connector` to read data from cassandra and process it in spark.
There are 2 billions rows in a cassandra table.
The schema is like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_keyspace.testtable (
    id text,
    code text,
    orgcode text,
    number bigint,
    branchnumber int,
    price decimal,
    content text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, code), orgcode, number, branchnumber)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (orgcode ASC, number ASC, branchnumber ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.1
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.DeflateCompressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
```

Using the following code to count **id**:

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> idRDD = javaFunctions(jsc).cassandraTable("my_keyspace", "testtable", mapColumnTo(String.class)).select("id")
idRDD.distinct().count();
```

But got the following error:

```
17/12/13 11:32:21 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 27.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 27, 10.240.0.30, executor 1): java.io.IOException: Exception during execution of SELECT "id" FROM "my_keyspace"."testtable" WHERE token("id", "code") > ? AND token("id", "code") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: Cassandra failure during reay at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:3
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:76)
```

All tasks in spark failed. And after a while, cassandra failed because of OOME.
There are 5 nodes on GCE to do this test. I have tried to expand `memory` and increase `request_timeout`, but they didn't work.

Environment:
spark: 2.1.2
cassandra: 3.10
spark-cassandra-connector: 2.0.6

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: no, I didn't continue investigating it